# How to see memory usage of ALL scoped variables

Tags: xpages

Is there any chance to see, how much memory is allocated by all scoped variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way is to use [yourKit java profiler](http://www.yourkit.com/).

You can install the agent on the Domino server and then profile the JVM. This will give you the ability to look and see what's going on during run time, see execution times, and see what the number of classes and instances loaded and how much memory they are consuming.

Comment: Tried it, but the agent ( 64Bit ) crashes my server. It connects to the server and remains stable for 10 seconds or so.

Comment: Windows 64bit I assume? can you post your agent options text file and I'll see if there is anything I can suggest. I've used it on Windows 32/64 and Linux 64 w/o issue.

Comment: -agentpath:D:\Programme\yjp\bin\win64/yjpagent.dll=listen=192.168.178.33:10001

Comment: Here is what I have used on my Win7 x64 with 8.5.2 or .3 without any issue, both on a local server, and remotely.

-agentpath:C:\PROGRA~2\YOURKI~1.2\bin\win64\yjpagent.dll=disablestacktelemetry,disableexceptiontelemetry,builtinprobes=none,delay=10000,listen=10001

Comment: Thx, Jeremy. It's now running stable on Win2008R2 with Domino 8.5.3.

Comment: I'm trying to do the same on my Domino 9.0.1 server and I am getting crashes. -agentpath:C:\ProgramData\YourKit\yjpagent_13082_64_603ABE4D.dll=disablestacktelemetry,disableexceptiontelemetry,delay=10000,listen=192.168.1.40:10001   I'm running Domino 64bit on Windows 8.1 (I know, I'm cheap) and I'm getting crashes. I'm also trying to get the JVM for the Agent Manager, but I don't know where that one is - more than one process is shown in my Task Manager.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you asked for, but it may help: type `tell http xsp heapdump` command on console. It will create heapdump file in binaries directory of Domino. Open that file in Heap Analyzer tool (http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21190608), also available in IBM Support Assistant (http://www-01.ibm.com/software/support/isa/).

Comment: I used the XPages toolbox from OpenNTF. Includes the information, I was looking for.